# Why does Google use 2 spaces instead of 4/8/whatever?

Tags: coding-style

Does anyone know why Google's coding standards ([C++ Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml) e.g. but I think the same applies to others as well) use 2 spaces for indentation instead of 4?

Comment: You could equally ask why do other places use 4 instead of 2.

Comment: @Tony True but given that 4 is considered some sort of standard, I was wondering why Google did not follow it.

Comment: Method: I have this feeling you won't accept "because they wanted to" as an answer. So I guess I won't post it...

Comment: I think this question has unfairly been closed. This **is** a real question. The poster is asking about Google's reasons for the 2-spaces style, not for a general discussion about the subject.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only reason I can think of is deeply nested code: with 4 spaces and a sufficient amount of nested `if`, loops or whatever, the leftmost half of your monitor will be obviously blank, if you're using a low resolution.
Personally I would always prefer 4, but I can see why somebody might want less than that while writing HTML, for instance.

Personal preferences really - most editors will use 4 spaces by default.

Comment: With 4 spaces per indent, 10 levels of indentation eat 40 chars, _half of your usable window width!_ In Java this hits particularly hard, with all these long identifiers, repeated type qualifiers, and nested anonymous classes.

Comment: I can only say that for as unreadable as code nested more the 4 or 5 layers deep is using 4-space indents, it is all the more awful trying to even tell what level of indentation you are looking at if it's 2-space indentation.  It's pretty hard to find code with more than 5 levels of indent that does not desperately need to be refactored.

Comment: I have to agree with orange80. It is an incredibly stupid reason to use 2 space indent because you have *10 levels of indentation*. The irony is Google Guava is will written code that hardly needs a couple levels of indentation. The two spaces hurts people with visual disabilities. At least with evil tabs people can change it and with 4 spaces everyone can still **read** the code which is far more important than convenience of writing code.